# stralloc implementation of string in qmail

Tags: email, qmail

what is the ending delimiter of string used through stralloc function in qmail(MTA) code???

```
stralloc str;
stralloc_copys(&str,"testing");
printf("%s\n", str.s);
```

It actually prints

> testingZjklfjndf

What is the correct way to print the content???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such there is no delimiter but you can find  Z at the end of every string stored by stralloc. the data stored in stralloc is looked-up though len only.

and as ansh already mentioned dont try to print the data through printf instead run a for loop for len times on the string.

for more reference: http://cr.yp.to/lib/stralloc.html

Answer (score 1):

in stralloc \0 is also a valid content so dont try to print the data through printf

Answer (score 1):

stralloc_0 will terminate the rest of the things after Z. But when u want to print , print till str.len.